# Tensorflow attention OCR inference code

Tags: tensorflow, attention-model

I am trying to run the attention ocr in the tensorflow models https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/attention_ocr . I can find the script for training and evaluating on the FSNS dataset but they do not have code to run inference on a single image. I want to test it with my images and see how good it performs. 
Here is what i tried for the inference part but I get error "Attempting to use uninitialized value AttentionOcr_v1/conv_tower_fn/INCE/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights"

```
      dataset = common_flags.create_dataset(split_name=FLAGS.split_name)
      model = common_flags.create_model(dataset.num_char_classes,
                                        dataset.max_sequence_length,
                                        1, dataset.null_code)

      #images: A tensor of shape [batch_size, height, width, channels].
      images_actual_data = Image.open("imagename.jpg").resize((600, 150))
      #Increase dimension of data and make it 4D
      images_actual_data = np.expand_dims(images_actual_data,axis=0)/255.0
      slim.get_or_create_global_step()  
      master_checkpoint = "trained_files/attention_ocr_2017_05_17/model.ckpt-399731"
      inception_checkpoint = "inception-v3_2016_08_28/inception_v3.ckpt"

#inference code
      with tf.Session() as sess:
        init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        sess.run(init_op)
        images_placeholder = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=(1,150,600,3))
        endpoints = model.create_base(images_placeholder, labels_one_hot=None)
        model.create_init_fn_to_restore(master_checkpoint, inception_checkpoint)
        predictions = sess.run(endpoints.predicted_chars, feed_dict={images_placeholder: images_actual_data})
```

> Here is the output log

```
    DEBUG 2017-08-01 21:20:58.000825: model.py: 314 images: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(1, 150, 600, 3), dtype=float32)
    DEBUG 2017-08-01 21:20:58.000827: model.py: 319 Views=1 single view: Tensor("AttentionOcr_v1/split:0", shape=(1, 150, 600, 3), dtype=float32)
    DEBUG 2017-08-01 21:20:58.000827: model.py: 186 Using final_endpoint=Mixed_5d
    DEBUG 2017-08-01 21:20:59.000906: model.py: 325 Conv tower: Tensor("AttentionOcr_v1/conv_tower_fn/INCE/InceptionV3/Mixed_5d/concat:0", shape=(1, 16, 72, 288), dtype=float32)
    DEBUG 2017-08-01 21:20:59.000909: model.py: 328 Pooled views: Tensor("AttentionOcr_v1/pool_views_fn/STCK/Reshape:0", shape=(1, 1152, 288), dtype=float32)
    DEBUG 2017-08-01 21:20:59.000909: sequence_layers.py: 421 Use AttentionWithAutoregression as a layer class
    DEBUG 2017-08-01 21:21:01.000588: model.py: 331 chars_logit: Tensor("AttentionOcr_v1/sequence_logit_fn/SQLR/concat:0", shape=(1, 37, 134), dtype=float32)
    INFO 2017-08-01 21:21:01.000864: model.py: 511 Request to re-store 117 weights from trained_files/attention_ocr_2017_05_17/model.ckpt-399731
    INFO 2017-08-01 21:21:02.000021: model.py: 511 Request to re-store 104 weights from inception-v3_2016_08_28/inception_v3.ckpt

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/sxa091/everything/example_projects/tf_projects/models/attention_ocr/python/eval_image.py", line 84, in <module>
        app.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
        _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
      File "/Users/sxa091/everything/example_projects/tf_projects/models/attention_ocr/python/eval_image.py", line 80, in main
        predictions = sess.run(endpoints.predicted_chars, feed_dict={images_placeholder: images_actual_data})
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
        run_metadata_ptr)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
        feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
        target_list, options, run_metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
        raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value AttentionOcr_v1/conv_tower_fn/INCE/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights
         [[Node: AttentionOcr_v1/conv_tower_fn/INCE/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@AttentionOcr_v1/conv_tower_fn/INCE/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](AttentionOcr_v1/conv_tower_fn/INCE/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights)]]
```

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @Niyaz The piece of code that I posted does not work because its incomplete. So, I was hoping if anyone could shed some light on how to write inference code for the attention_ocr model. Thanks.

Comment: If you loading weights from a master checkpoint you don't need to specify the inception checkpoint.

Comment: So I tried setting only the master ckeckpoint.
        model.create_init_fn_to_restore(master_checkpoint, inception_checkpoint = None)
I still get the same error.

Comment: Ok, it looks like something is broken. I'll take a closer look https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2137

Comment: we uploaded a new checkpoint with fixed tensor names
http://download.tensorflow.org/models/attention_ocr_2017_08_09.tar.gz
please try it and let me know how it works. Here is also an example of the code to run an inference on a trained model
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/2166

Comment: @AlexanderGorban Thanks much. I will checkout it out and then post the results.

Comment: @AlexanderGorban
I tried the new demo_inference.py code from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/2166
And used the checkpoint at http://download.tensorflow.org/models/attention_ocr_2017_08_09.tar.gz

And I get the following error
ValueError: Checkpoint is missing variable 
  
  [AttentionOcr_v1/sequence_logit_fn/SQLR/LSTM/attention_decoder/lstm_cell/weights]

Comment: Okay I tried the demo_inference.py code from github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/2166 again but this time I used the old checkpoint at http://download.tensorflow.org/models/attention_ocr_2017_05_17.tar.gz
And the problem is fixed and the inference part is running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has his own favorite way to store and read images, so this snippet is incomplete intentionally.

Here is one many possible ways to populate the images_actual_data:

```
import skimage.io as io
import numpy as np

fn = '600x150_image_with_4_views_%i.jpg'
images = [io.imread(fn % i, dtype='float') for i in range(batch_size)]
images_actual_data = np.stack(images)
images_actual_data = 2.5*(images_actual_data - 0.5)  # normalize values
```

Note that you need to use the same type of the [normalization which was used during training](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3eba37c/attention_ocr/python/data_provider.py#L147).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I have edited the question with log of my error message and the image loading part as well. The error looks like it is not able to load the inception checkpoint. The path to checkpoints are correct.
Can you please explain what might be the cause?

Comment: You've updated your question and now it's a new question altogether. So my current answer doesn't look like a relevant anymore, please create new questions in such cases.

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have posted the entire code in the beginning.